# Oracle: outer join(+) with or clause replacement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have an enormous select that schematically looks like this:

```
SELECT c_1, c_2, ..., c_j FROM t_1, t_2, ..., t_k
WHERE e_11 = e_12(+)
AND e_21 = e_22(+)
AND ...
AND e_l1 = e_l2(+)
ORDER BY o
```

where `j`, `k` and `l` are in hundreds and `e_mn` is a column from some table. I need to add new columns `A_1` and `A_2` to the select from a new table `T`. The new columns are connected to the former select via a column call it `B` from a table `R`. I want those rows where `A_1 = B` or `A_2 = B` or those rows where there is no correspondeing `A_i` to the value `B`.

Suppose I only had to deal with tables `T` and `R` then I want this:

```
SELECT * FROM R
LEFT OUTER JOIN T
ON (A_1 = B OR A_2 = B)
```

To mimic this behaviour I'd want something like this in the big select:

```
SELECT c_1, c_2, ..., c_j, A_1, A_2 FROM t_1, t_2, ..., t_k, T
WHERE e_11 = e_12(+)
AND e_21 = e_22(+)
AND ...
AND e_l1 = e_l2(+)
AND (B = A_1(+) OR B = A_2(+))
ORDER BY o
```

this is, however, syntactically incorrect since the (+) operator cannot be used with the OR caluse. And if I leave out the (+)'s I lose those rows where there is no corresponding `A_i` to `B`.

What are my options here? Can I somehow find a way to do this *without* changing the whole body of the select? I doubt there is a reasonable way to do this, nevertheless I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do ANSI JOIN syntax beyond having to replace the existing code (and test)?

Comment: @ChrisCameron-Mills It was suggested to me that I don't change the previous code, it is for a company so. But if there is no other way I'll have to either change that or change the DB model.

Comment: If the query is so horrendous then I would suggest refactoring it using ANSII join syntax and CTEs. Modifying next time round will be so much easier. As for testing - well you are going to have to do that anyway.

Comment: You can also use UNION ALL query with each condition.